# Pull all unfetched changes from git repository

Tags: git, repository

I need to fetch everything from a few different, distinct repositories (all remote branches and all changes to those branches). I tried `git pull --all` but for some reason, I get the following message:

```
There are no candidates for merging among the refs that you just fetched.
Generally this means that you provided a wildcard refspec which had no
matches on the remote end.
```

So how would I go about ensuring that I get all the changes from a repository (without knowing what branches are on the other end, if possible)?

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the scenario where you would need to do this? Sounds kind of like a bad idea...

Comment: icco - well, I've deleted some branches from some of my projects by accident. And somehow crippled my server during updates. But I somehow got git to work, so I want to back stuff up before nuking it and starting over.

Comment: So you have one repository with multiple remotes and each have different branches than each other? This sounds like a miserable set up... Are all of your remotes on this broken machine?

Comment: Just wanted to add a note that you can see branches that map from local to remote via `git remote show remotename` (I just discovered this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking -- that's a really, really bad idea. Don't do that. "All remote branches" will often include work-in-progress code, abandoned code, conflicting implementations of the same feature, etc. Trying to merge them all into your local tree is a recipe for disaster.

Now, if you *really wanted* to do the very silly thing you suggested, you could do it something like thus:

```
git fetch remote_source
git merge $(git branch -r | grep remote_source)
```

Now, if all you really want to do is *have a local copy* of all remote changes, without trying to merge them into your tree, then you don't need to do a pull or merge at all; `git fetch remote_source` does it all for you. Sure, it doesn't create local branches mapped to the remotes -- but it does pull down the remote branches, and you can create local ones when and as you need them, with no further communication with the remote source required.

---

Given further problem description in the comments, it sounds like what you *really* want is to push all branches from your old remote to a new remote, *not* to merge them into a single tree. To do this, you'd probably want something like the following:

```
args=()
for remote_branch in $(git branch -r | grep OLD_REMOTE/); do
  branch_name=${remote_branch#*/}
  args+=( "${remote_branch}:${branch_name}" )
done
git push NEW_REMOTE "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: I agree that it would be quite a bad idea -- IF the repositories were not just used by me. Now since what I'm trying to do is get the data, restore my server to some semblance of working order, and then restore all this data, would just a fetch (and then a push? or would I need to merge for that?) work? Thanks!

Comment: @adam_0, just a fetch gathers all the data. It doesn't merge it, but it makes it all available... such that you _do_ at that point have all the remote branches available at your local copy.

Comment: So if I were to fetch the data, and then push to a new remote, would all the data be transferred? Or would git want me to specify branches? If I can do this, problem solved

Comment: @adam_0, a push will not include data not referenced by any local branch by default. For each branch `foo`, however, you could do the following: `git push new_remote old_remote/foo:foo`

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a very bad idea. But I guess you know what you are doing.

I use the following bash one liner though to do pushes to all remotes, which I've modified to do pulls instead.

```
for i in $(git remote); do git pull $i master; done;
```

Comment: That would work fantastically, except I don't have all of the remotes on my local copy.